# How to update a field CONCAT with auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a region field that checks the count existing on my table. If the count is 0 it will start as 01 (e.g SG01). I am currently looking for a query that checks again when and if the region keyword has been changed, it will check again and there are existing in the table it will add depending on the region (e.g VN02 if there is already VN01).

Here's my query for inserting

```
INSERT INTO tbl_regions(region_ID, region_Name, company_Name, region_Address, region_Keyword) 
    SELECT :region_ID, :region_name, :company_name, :region_address,
           CONCAT(:region_keyword, LPAD(COUNT(region_Keyword) +1,2,0))
    FROM tbl_regions
    WHERE region_Keyword LIKE '%:region_keyword%'")
```

currently looking for a query if i would update the region_keyword field.

Comment: This is difficult, because there is no guarantee that the auto increment sequence would always be continually increasing.  What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: I suggest using a computed column.

Comment: Note: Placeholder values do not normally support that sort of interpolation. You'll want to instead do `CONCAT('%', :region_keyword, '%')` or add the `%` things to what you're binding instead.

Comment: Hi @tadman thanks for the suggestion, Actually insertion works as is .I'll worked on that though the issue I'm working on is on the update process. any suggestions ? .

Comment: It sounds like you need a sequence generator. Have a look fro those.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite dangerous as it is subject to concurrency issues. I would suggest using a stored procedure with `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` to assure that you don't end up with duplicate values. It also makes it simple to create a variable to parse the greatest region ID and increment the value.